# How to make the footer the same width as the content using vuetify?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

The footer in this code expands the entire window width. I want it to be the same width as the `<v-content>`

```
  <v-app>
    <v-navigation-drawer permanent app>
    </v-navigation-drawer>
    <v-content>
      <v-container fluid>
        <router-view></router-view>
      </v-container>
    </v-content>
    <v-footer app>
      <p>&copy;</p>
    </v-footer>
  </v-app>
```

Comment: Your description is not enough for me

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use the `app` prop on the `<footer>` if you want it to be the same width as the content, you should rather put it inside the `<v-content>`, and then put the `absolute` prop, just as the following:

```
<v-app>
  <v-navigation-drawer permanent app>
  </v-navigation-drawer>
  <v-content>
    <v-container fluid>
      <router-view></router-view>
    </v-container>
    <v-footer absolute>
      <p>&copy;</p>
    </v-footer>
  </v-content>
</v-app>
```

Edit/Approach 2: You can also use the `inset` prop on the `<footer>` to make an offset from the navigation drawer, if you want to keep the footer out of the `<content>`.

```
<v-app>
  <v-navigation-drawer permanent app>
  </v-navigation-drawer>
  <v-content>
    <v-container fluid>
      <router-view></router-view>
    </v-container>
  </v-content>
  <v-footer inset app>
    <p>&copy;</p>
  </v-footer>
</v-app>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another working example just add `inset` to v-footer

```
<v-app>
    <v-navigation-drawer permanent app>
    </v-navigation-drawer>
    <v-content>
      <v-container fluid>
        <router-view></router-view>
      </v-container>
    </v-content>
    <v-footer inset app>
      <p>&copy;</p>
    </v-footer>
 </v-app>
```